# How can I get IndexPath of currently selected tableviewcell by voice over?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath, voiceover

I'm using Voice Over in my application. I'm having hard time to figure out which table cell is currently selected when voice over is on. How can I know whenever user initiates single tap or navigate through any tableviewcell?

Comment: inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method you can get indexpath of selected cell using `indexPath.row`.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav. For that I have to double tap on my screen. I want indexPath when user initiates single tap. On single tap, voice over selects the tableviewcell. So how can I get the indexPath on single tap? Because after single tap, I need indexPath when user swipes for further operations.

Comment: Voice over doesn't select any item it just read the caption, after second tap item will be selected. Blind people use voice over for navigation, so if you need to add something just for blind people - use `accessibilityLabel `

Comment: @ NSDmitry I have updated my question adding more info. After user navigates to particular cell, I'm hinting user to swipe for particular operation. So I need indexPath for that. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

These are the things you can try:

- use the `UIAccessibilityFocusedElement` global function
- override `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` and `accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus` on the cell
- observe the `UIAccessibilityElementFocused` notification in `NotificationCenter` in situations where you need it (e.g. when the view controller for the table in question is showing)

Also what element will report focus will most probably depend on whether your UITableViewCell has `isAccessibilityElement` set to `true` or `false`.

While the above will probably help you with literally what you asked, it is also possible that your overall approach to accessibility in this situation might be wrong if you need the above information. If you share more info on the bigger picture / motivation what you are trying to achieve, it might turn out that the information about focused element might not be needed at all and that another solution is more proper.

If what you need is to add a hint for swiping, you can simply set `accessibilityHint` on the proper element (if you set `isAccessibilityElement = true` on the whole cell, then set that on the whole cell, otherwise try setting it on the label that VoiceOver reads in the cell), e.g. when you configure the cell for display (usually in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`). In such case, you will not need to observe which element is focused, and simply let VoiceOver read hint available on that particular element/cell.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have used cell.accessibilityHint = @"Swipe Left To Add To My List. Swipe Right To Play. Swipe Up To Share. Swipe Down For More Info.";      After voice over jumps to particular cell, it will announce cell's accessibility hint. So user can then swipe for mentioned operation. Now user swipes  down for more info about element in current cell, I transit the screen by giving element id. How can I get this element id from array? Thats why I needed indexPath.

Comment: @HirenPrajapati please confirm myunderstanding: when VO cursor moves to the cell, VO announces the hint you set. You have configured 2 `UIAccessibilityCustomAction`s on the cell, one for Sharing, one for "More info". The target of both actions is the view controller, not the cell, so you need a way for the view controller to get the index of cell where VoiceOver cursor is: in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath `, you have it as a parameter, in prepareForSegue, you can use index of sender or `indexPathForSelectedRows`, so you simply want an analog to get the selected index in accessibility action target?

Comment: @HirenPrajapati you might also want to use the `UIAccessibilityFocusedElement` global function, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I really don't know how to use these functions and how they get called. I already have used accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() method but it doesn't get called. And I haven't used UIAccessibilityCustomActions and I don't even know to use it. I use accessibilityScroll() which gives swiping direction, so I call my operations accordingly. And didSelectRowAtIndexPath() will only get called when voice over user double taps. I'm talking about focus or single tap on row. Please help.

Comment: Hey. How can I get CGPoint of currently focused element when voice over is enabled?